# iOS, Force layout a view controller in the background with completion block?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Is this possible?

Once I instantiate the view controller from another class I want to:

- Force layout: Load/draw the view controller's UI including all constraints.
- Have a completion block telling me when this is complete (similar to viewDidAppear)
- Do this off-screen without presenting the view controller.

Cheers!

Comment: You can instantiate the view controller and then use a delegate to call back when `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is complete.

Comment: If you mean from a background thread, the answer is a hard *no*. You should not run UI code from a background thread. If you are hoping to do your layout before displaying the view controller, that's how it works now. The system tells the views to lay themselves out while they are still hidden, and then displays them so they show up at the correct size and location.